# Change grading type depending on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a grading system for a webpage and I'm trying to change the way the grade is interpreted when the column is clicked (i.e. Average (%) \ Letters \ 4.0 Grade Average. I'm using Jquery to calculate the average of 5 assignments in the table under the function findAvg(). I devised an algorithm to change the grades but I can't seem to get it to work, if anyone could point out where I have gone wrong I would really appreciate it.

```js
const finalgrade = document.getElementById("finalgrade");
// const as1 = document.querySelector('#as1');
// const as2 = document.querySelector('#as2');
// const as3 = document.querySelector('#as3');
// const as4 = document.querySelector('#as4');
// const as5 = document.querySelector('#as5');
// let cells = [];
let avg;
let count = 0;
let finalGrades = [];
// let type = [0, 1, 2];
let pointer = 0;
let letters = ["A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"];
let scales = [4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.0];

console.log(finalGrades);

function findAvg() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    count = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
      var totalmarks = 0;
      $(this).find('.assignments').each(function() {
        var marks = $(this).text(); {
          if (marks.length !== 0) {
            totalmarks += parseFloat(marks);
            count++;
          }
        }
      });
      avg = Math.round(totalmarks / 5);
      finalGrades.push(avg);
      $(this).find('.finalmark').html(avg);
    });
  });
}

finalgrade.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //console.log("123");
  switch (pointer) {
    case 0:
      pointer = 1;
      getGrade(pointer);
      break;
    case 1:
      pointer = 2;
      getGrade(pointer);
      break;
    case 2:
      pointer = 0;
      findAvg();
      break;
  }

});

function getGrade(pointer) {
  if (pointer === 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < finalGrades.length; i++) {
      if (finalGrades[i] > 92 && finalGrades[i] < 101) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 89 && finalGrades[i] < 93) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 86 && finalGrades[i] < 90) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 82 && finalGrades[i] < 87) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 79 && finalGrades[i] < 83) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 76 && finalGrades[i] < 80) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 72 && finalGrades[i] < 77) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 69 && finalGrades[i] < 73) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 66 && finalGrades[i] < 70) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 62 && finalGrades[i] < 67) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else if (finalGrades[i] > 59 && finalGrades[i] < 63) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
      else finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
    }
  } else if (pointer === 2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      finalGrades[i] = scales[i];
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < scales; i++) {
      finalGrades[i] = scales[i];
    }
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Student Grades</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th id="as1">Assignment 1</th>
      <th id="as2">Assignment 2</th>
      <th id="as3">Assignment 3</th>
      <th id="as4">Assignment 4</th>
      <th id="as5">Assignment 5</th>
      <th id="finalgrade">Average [%]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>18401696</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>18401900</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>18401800</td>
      <td class="assignments">70</td>
      <td class="assignments">70</td>
      <td class="assignments">65</td>
      <td class="assignments">45</td>
      <td class="assignments">56</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>18401000</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>18401231</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>18401656</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>18405423</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>18401987</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>18400000</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>18401111</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are calling 
    $(document).ready(function() from function findAvg() {. move the function outside and use jQuery to access $("#finalgrade")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a corrected script - note I moved the function and the document.ready ( $(function(){}) )

```js
let avg;
let count = 0;
let pointer = 0;
let finalGrades = [];
let avgs = [];
let letters = ["A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"];
let scales = [4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.0];

let gradeLetters = []
let gradeAvgs = []
let gradeScale = []

function makeTotals() {
  count = 0;
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var totalmarks = 0;
    $(this).find('.assignments').each(function() {
      var marks = $(this).text(); {
        if (marks.length !== 0) {
          totalmarks += parseFloat(marks);
          count++;
        }
      }
    });
    finalGrades.push(totalmarks);
    avg = Math.round(totalmarks / 5);
    gradeAvgs.push(avg);
    if (totalmarks > 101) {
      gradeLetters.push("A+");
      gradeScale.push("Off");

    } else
    if (totalmarks > 92 && totalmarks < 101) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[0]);
      gradeScale.push(scales[0]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 89 && totalmarks < 93) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[1])
      gradeScale.push(scales[1]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 86 && totalmarks < 90) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[2])
      gradeScale.push(scales[2]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 82 && totalmarks < 87) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[3])
      gradeScale.push(scales[3]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 79 && totalmarks < 83) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[4])
      gradeScale.push(scales[4]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 76 && totalmarks < 80) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[5])
      gradeScale.push(scales[5]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 72 && totalmarks < 77) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[6])
      gradeScale.push(scales[6]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 69 && totalmarks < 73) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[7])
      gradeScale.push(scales[7]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 66 && totalmarks < 70) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[8])
      gradeScale.push(scales[8]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 62 && totalmarks < 67) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[9])
      gradeScale.push(scales[9]);
    } else if (totalmarks > 59 && totalmarks < 63) {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[10])
      gradeScale.push(scales[10]);
    } else {
      gradeLetters.push(letters[11])
      gradeScale.push(scales[11]);
    }
    console.log("tm", totalmarks)
  });
}

$(function() {
  makeTotals();
  showGrade();
  $("#finalgrade").on('click', () => {
    pointer++;
    if (pointer >= 3) pointer = 0;
    showGrade();
  });
});

function showGrade() {
  [...$(".finalmark")].forEach((fm, i) => {
    if (pointer === 0) {
      $(fm).text(gradeAvgs[i])
      $("#finalgrade").text("Average [%]")
    } else if (pointer === 1) {
      $(fm).text(gradeScale[i])
      $("#finalgrade").text("Scale")
    } else {
      $(fm).text(gradeLetters[i])
      $("#finalgrade").text("Letter")
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#finalgrade {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Student Grades</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th id="as1">Assignment 1</th>
      <th id="as2">Assignment 2</th>
      <th id="as3">Assignment 3</th>
      <th id="as4">Assignment 4</th>
      <th id="as5">Assignment 5</th>
      <th id="finalgrade">Average [%]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>18401696</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>18401900</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>18401800</td>
      <td class="assignments">70</td>
      <td class="assignments">70</td>
      <td class="assignments">65</td>
      <td class="assignments">45</td>
      <td class="assignments">56</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>18401000</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>18401231</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>18401656</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>18405423</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>18401987</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>18400000</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>18401111</td>
      <td class="assignments">1</td>
      <td class="assignments">2</td>
      <td class="assignments">3</td>
      <td class="assignments">4</td>
      <td class="assignments">5</td>
      <td class="finalmark"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The pointer is set to 0 from the beginning signifying 0 as the default grading scheme (average %) then when clicked it would change from 0 to 1, or 1 to 2, or 2 back to 0 (0 = average, 1 = letters, 2 = 4.0 grading) so you can switch between them as many times as needed.

Comment: So the code should work now I moved the functions to the right places?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still isn't providing the output, nothing happens for this first 2 clicks and on the third click, it displays the average %. Any clicks after that have no effect on anything. Could the issue be with the algorithm? Or could it be in the pointer variable and the switch statement calls?

Comment: What am I supposed to do - give me a list of thing to do

Comment: Okay, so the average should be displayed when the page loads. When the column is clicked it should alternate between displaying average %, letter equivalent or 4.0 grade equivalent. All these values should be displayed in the last column cells. Does that make sense? If not let me know, thanks again i really appreciate it

Comment: Ok, one step further. We still need to output the finalGrades array

Comment: Could we use something like this in the getGrades method rather than outptting the final grades array:                                                                                                                         if (finalGrades[i] > 92 && finalGrades[i] < 101) {
                $('tr').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[0]);
                });
            }          //This would be for the letter A in the letters array

Comment: @phelo_lad Please look now. The values in the cells do not make sense when compared to the values you calculate. Too small and one too big. I think my code will work if you have relevant numbers in the cells

Comment: Thanks very much @mplungjan that works, thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, used jquery similar to the findavg method

```js
let avg;
let count = 0;
let finalGrades = [];
// let type = [0, 1, 2];
let pointer = 0;
let letters = ["A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"];
let scales = [4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.0];

function findAvg() {
    count = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
        var totalmarks = 0;
        $(this).find('.assignments').each(function() {
            var marks = $(this).text(); {
                if (marks !== "-") {
                    totalmarks += parseFloat(marks);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
        avg = Math.round(totalmarks / 5);
        finalGrades.push(avg);
        $(this).find('.finalmark').html(avg);
    });
}

// $(function() {
//     $('tr').each(function () {
//         $(this).find('#finalgrade').each(function () {
//             var marks = $(this).text();
//             var average = parseInt(marks);
//             {
//                 if (average < 60) {
//                     $(this).find('tr').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
//                 }
//             }
//         });
//     });
// });

$(function() {
    $("#finalgrade").on('click', () => {
        //console.log("123");
        switch (pointer) {
            case 0:
                pointer = 1;
                getGrade(pointer);
                break;
            case 1:
                pointer = 2;
                getGrade(pointer);
                break;
            case 2:
                pointer = 0;
                findAvg();
                break;
        }

    });
});

function getGrade(pointer) {
    if (pointer === 1) {
        // for (let i = 0; i < finalGrades.length; i++) {
        //     if (finalGrades[i] > 92 && finalGrades[i] < 101) {
        //         $('tr').each(function() {
        //             $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[0]);
        //         });
        //     }
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 89 && finalGrades[i] < 93) {
        //         // $(function() {
        //         //     $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[1]);
        //         // });
        //     }
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 86 && finalGrades[i] < 90) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 82 && finalGrades[i] < 87) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 79 && finalGrades[i] < 83) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 76 && finalGrades[i] < 80) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 72 && finalGrades[i] < 77) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 69 && finalGrades[i] < 73) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 66 && finalGrades[i] < 70) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 62 && finalGrades[i] < 67) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else if (finalGrades[i] > 59 && finalGrades[i] < 63) finalGrades[i] = letters[i];
        //     else finalGrades[i] = letters[i];

        $('tr').each(function() {
            var totalmarks = 0;
            $(this).find('.assignments').each(function() {
                var marks = $(this).text(); {
                    if (marks !== "-") {
                        totalmarks += parseFloat(marks);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });
            avg = Math.round(totalmarks / 5);
            finalGrades.push(avg);
            if(avg > 92 && avg < 101) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[0]);
            }
            else if(avg > 89 && avg < 93) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[1]);
            }
            else if(avg > 85 && avg < 91) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[2]);
            }
            else if(avg > 82 && avg < 87) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[3]);
            }
            else if(avg > 79 && avg < 83) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[4]);
            }
            else if(avg > 76 && avg < 80) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[5]);
            }
            else if(avg > 72 && avg < 77) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[6]);
            }
            else if(avg > 69 && avg < 73) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[7]);
            }
            else if(avg > 66 && avg < 70) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[8]);
            }
            else if(avg > 62 && avg < 67) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[9]);
            }
            else if(avg > 59 && avg < 63) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[10]);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(letters[11])
            }
        });

        //}
    } else if (pointer === 2) {
        $('tr').each(function() {
            var totalmarks = 0;
            $(this).find('.assignments').each(function() {
                var marks = $(this).text(); {
                    if (marks !== "-") {
                        totalmarks += parseFloat(marks);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });
            avg = Math.round(totalmarks / 5);
            finalGrades.push(avg);
            if(avg > 92 && avg < 101) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[0] + ".0");
            }
            else if(avg > 89 && avg < 93) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[1]);
            }
            else if(avg > 85 && avg < 91) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[2]);
            }
            else if(avg > 82 && avg < 87) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[3] + ".0");
            }
            else if(avg > 79 && avg < 83) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[4]);
            }
            else if(avg > 76 && avg < 80) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[5]);
            }
            else if(avg > 72 && avg < 77) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[6] + ".0");
            }
            else if(avg > 69 && avg < 73) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[7]);
            }
            else if(avg > 66 && avg < 70) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[8]);
            }
            else if(avg > 62 && avg < 67) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[9] +".0");
            }
            else if(avg > 59 && avg < 63) {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[10]);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('.finalmark').html(scales[11] + ".0")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.51);
}

th {
    background-color: grey;
}

h3 {
    alignment: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student Grades</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th id="studentName"><h3>Student Name</h3></th>
            <th id="studentID"><h3>Student ID</h3></th>
            <th id="as1"><h3>Assignment 1</h3></th>
            <th id="as2"><h3>Assignment 2</h3></th>
            <th id="as3"><h3>Assignment 3</h3></th>
            <th id="as4"><h3>Assignment 4</h3></th>
            <th id="as5"><h3>Assignment 5</h3></th>
            <th id="finalgrade"><h3>Average [%]</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">a</td>
            <td align="left">18401696</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">1</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">2</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">3</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">4</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">5</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">b</td>
            <td align="left">18401900</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">c</td>
            <td align="left">18401800</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">d</td>
            <td align="left">18401000</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">e</td>
            <td align="left">18401231</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">f</td>
            <td align="left">18401656</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">g</td>
            <td align="left">18405423</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">h</td>
            <td align="left">18401987</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">i</td>
            <td align="left">18400000</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">j</td>
            <td align="left">18401111</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="assignments" align="right" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="findAvg()">-</td>
            <td class="finalmark" align="right"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <!--<button onclick="productsAdd()">Add Entry</button>-->
</body>
</html>
```